# How would you hide the specific ORM implementation in: class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, abstraction

Let's say I have a model class called Project, but instead of this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
```

I wanted to write this:

```
class Project < ORM
```

so that the specific ORM implementation is not present in my model class.

How would I need to write my ORM class so that the Project class above is able to act as a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base` but without specifically subclassing it?

Would I simply say:

```
class ORM < ActiveRecord::Base
```

and then Project would be a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base` just the same as if I had written:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly an easier way to do this would be to just assign `ActiveRecord::Base`:

```
ORM = ActiveRecord::Base

class Project < ORM
end
```

Then, if you wanted to swap to a different implementation later, you could just change the assignment to ORM.